# Build a simple robot to learn ROS

Tags: arduino, ros, slam, ultrasonic-sensors

I am a beginner to ROS and I wanted to know if I could build a simple robot to learn ROS. 
I currently have the following components available:

1. Arduino Uno
2. Simple two wheeled robot chassis
3. Some motors
4. L293D motor driver
5. Some ultrasonic sensors
6. Some infrared sensors

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Shubham Jha, but I'm afraid that *Life Questions* are off-topic. Questions about choosing how to spend your time (what book to read, which class to take, what robotics project to construct, what career to pursue, etc.) may be about difficult decisions, & they are often important, but they are too specific to your own situation & are unlikely to help future visitors to the site. They would be better off asked in [chat]. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, see [ask] & [about].

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in learning ROS but do not have sophisticated hardware available, you can use the Gazebo simulator to simulate a robot and use ROS with that.

Keep in mind that ROS is not the only way to write software for robots, and also not necessarily the best way.

Answer (score 1):

ROS generally requires a full x86 or x64 computer, such as an Intel NUC. This can then communicate to things like arduino, but the brains of the computer is in the NUC.

As such, ROS is intended for large projects, and may be unsuitable for a hobby project. If this is to be your first adventures into robotics, stick with arduino for now. When you want to build a robot that can vacuum your house, wash the dishes and drive your car, then ROS is probably the thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

ROS is a sophisticated Robotics platform. So the minimum, You'll need a board with an operating system capabilities, like Raspberry Pi, banana pi, or beaglebone (you could try very cheap orange pi).

Or theoretically (I would like to try this too), you can make a tethered Arduino board connected to wifi using wifi module and send commands using Firmata protocol from the host computer.